# How to keep data history in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I saw many threads asking about keeping history of records in mysql. However, I'm not quite sure they are suitable with my case.

I'm developing an application form with a lot of user information. So far, I have to normalize it into 12 tables even though most of them have 1:1 relations but I though they would be good in the future use:

- User (Id, Fullname, Username, Email, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate, ...)
- Family (Id, UserId, Name, Relation, Job, ...)
- Address (Id, UserId, Road, District, Province, ...)
- ...

When clients filled all the fields in the form, they have two options, firstly, they can save it as draft, secondly, they can confirm sending the application and can't change it anymore.

I have done some research so far. They are many ways to do it. For example, I could duplicate all the tables with some additional fields; VersionId. However due to the enormous number of tables, I don't think it's a good idea.

So, what I think is to add `VersionId` to each existing tables. When they save the form as draft, I would just put the information without touching the `VersionId` field, however, I would increase `VersionId` by 1 whenever the user confirm submitting the application.

Any suggestion would be really welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `status` column to each table. It can have the values `draft`, `current`, and `history`.

When the user makes a change to their data, create a new row with `status = draft`. As they edit, you modify that row. When they confirm the changes, you set the old `current` row's status to `history`, and set the draft row's status to `current`.

Comment: Great suggestion. However, if they applied the application once again in the next year, in this case, the database would have two rows with status history. So, I would have to create another column to keep track, which one is more recent, wouldn't I?

Comment: The idea is that you'll have many rows with status history. This keeps a record of all the changes they've made to the record, with the `updateDate` showing the order of the changes.

Comment: As I have many tables; an address, a family, and etc, I would like to join all the tables in order to get the complete information submitted by a client in a specific version that I want to see. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: Given a particular timestamp, get the row from each table with highest `UpdatedTime` that's less than that timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I think it mainly depends on the business requirement (since it doesn't sound like there would be so many updates for the same user I am assuming that performance is not a concern but you may want to think about that too since an insert in this case is cheaper than an update).

So the question you need to ask yourself is does the business require that you keep the history or not? for example if user A fills out the form, and later on he updates some of the information e.g. he has a new address, do you want to be able to know what were his previous addresses or not? If you do then you have to store them (I would add the date of the change in addition to the version id)